# Has or Have for the semi-modal verb "Have to" when making question and negative sentences?

Tags: modal-verbs

Considering the semi-modal verb ***"Have to"*** Which of these sentences is correct grammatically:

Question form:
1- Does he **have** to wear his uniform?
2- Does he **has** to wear his uniform?

Negative form:
1- He doesn't **have** to wear his uniform.
2- He doesn't **has** to wear his uniform.

Comment: Preliminary point: the verb is just "have". "To" is a separate word; a subordinator introducing the infinitival verb phrase that follows "have". And "have" is not a modal verb either since it can combine with a modal verb ("We may have to cancel"); note that modal verbs cannot combine with other modals. Meaningwise, this "have"  does express obligation just like the genuine modal "must" does, but is not itself a modal verb. In your examples, the verb-form should be the plain form "have" because it follows the auxiliary verb "does".

Comment: @BillJ - Very helpful explanation and it ought to be copied into the answer box rather than just being a comment.

Comment: Actually, many linguists consider *have to* to be a semi-modal verb, apart from *have* as in possess. @BillJ And *had to* is used as the "past tense"  of "must"  in reported speech. And  last in some dialects, modals can be doubled or tripled: *She might could wait a year before she gets hitched.*

Comment: @AlanCarmack. I totally disagree. "Have" has none of the properties of a modal verb and so does not belong in that class (note for example that unlike modal verbs it takes _to_ infinitival complements). Reported speech is irrelevant; the syntax is totally different. The doubling up of modals is not standard English by any means; citing an example like yours on the site is simply absurd.

Comment: Google books search for ["have to" semi-modal](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="have+to"++semi-modal+), whether @BillJ agrees or not.

Comment: @AlanCarmack. I don't agree. And in any case, the OP seems happy, so why are you citing non-standard usage and analysis which could be highly misleading? And please don't post any more examples like yours; to give the impression that it is representative of Standard English is quite wrong.

Comment: @BillJ You have to read what I actually wrote: *some dialects*. And the analysis of *have to* as a semi-modal is not at all misleading.

Comment: @AlanCArmack I did read it; that's why I said that it is **not** Standard English! And nor is the analysis of "have to" as a modal, semi or otherwise.

Comment: There are copious sources which discuss the form "have to," but most of them are at pains to state that although we treat it as a modal verb ("for convenience") it is in fact just a usage of "have" as a main verb, e.g. [link](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modals-have-to-must-not-1.htm). Yet one answer at english.SE (with 16 votes!) states: "Have to is **not** a usage of the verb have, in any of its senses, though it used to be." [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/276394/why-do-the-sentences-i-have-to-get-a-job-and-i-need-to-get-a-job-mean-the-sa/276408#276408). Argh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both the Question and the Negative form, your first sentences are grammatically correct:

> **Does** he **have** to wear his uniform?

...and

> He **doesn't have** to wear his uniform.